# Difference between JSON.stringify(response.json()) and response.text()

Tags: javascript, json

After converting a response stream into JSON, are the two exactly the same?

```
const responseA = fetch(endpointReturnsJson)
const textA = await responseA.text()
```

In a parallel universe...

```
const responseA = fetch(endpointReturnsJson)
const json = await responseA.json()
const textB = JSON.stringify(json)
```

I understand that textB will likely include serialization of characters such as `{\\`
Is there anything else?

Comment: First of all you are missing `await` in front of both `fetch` and `response.json`/`response.text`. And assuming the response was valid JSON in the first place: `JSON.parse(await response.text())` should give the same result as `await response.json()`, but not necessarily the other way round because for example the whitespace may be different.

Comment: Thank you! Haha incorrectly contrived

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what `stuff` is.

If you use `response.json()`, you are assuming that the incoming stream was JSON-encoded. The method will take the stream's body's text and parse it.

When the data is not in JSON format, then access it with `response.text()` and process it accordingly.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response